# Проблема с выбором данных из базы данных в консоль

Tags: java, база-данных, sqlite, eclipse

Не могу вытащить информацию в консоль с БД, более детальное описание вопроса в картинке ниже:

[image: Описание:]

[Вот ссылка на сам проектик из трёх небольших классов:](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9Fhyy0NNKeGM21HZTZXT0kxbEU/view?usp=sharing) пожалуйста помогите разобраться, заранее спасибо!

Кстати создавал таблицу [Sqlite менеджером:](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B9Fhyy0NNKeGclhhLWt0VEpnbGM?usp=sharing)

Comment: Постарайте здесь приветси минимально воспроизводимый пример!

Comment: Используйте кнопку "Пример кода" (Ctrl+K) для добавления кода. Сообщение должно быть самодостаточным, ссылки на ресурсы могут служить только дополнением. Ошибки следуют добавлять в виде текста, а не картинок.

Comment: Спасибо за советы, учту на будущее. Последующие буду оформлять по другому.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Старайтесь использовать try с ресурсами и почитайте доки о интерфейсе `Statement`. `NullPointerException` было потому, что поле statement не было проинициализировано.

```
public class DbHandler {
private static final String SELECT_ALL = "SELECT * FROM user";
private Connection connector;

public DbHandler() {
    try {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        connector = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:db/contacts.db");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Успешно подключена База данных");
    } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void getData() {
    try (Statement statement = this.connector.createStatement()) {
        try (ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(SELECT_ALL)) {
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                System.out.print(resultSet.getString(1) + " ");
                System.out.print(resultSet.getString(2) + " ");
                System.out.println(resultSet.getString(3));
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!!!, но маленький вопрос, а при необходимости мне в каждом методе придётся создавать  новые классы Statement и ResultSet?

Comment: @Виктор Можно создать поле ResultSet resultSet; к примеру. А в методе getData() присвоить этому полю тот resultSet который объявлен в getData(). this.resultSet = result.Set; Получиться, что resultSet - поле будет ссылаться на объект resultSet, который объявлен в методе. Не знаю насколько это верно. Но я бы сделал так.